# React testing shallow snapshots problem with prop

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have problem with testing react component that has some HOC around it.
This is the end of this component:

```
export default withSocket(withServerConfiguration(Component));
```

I would like to test it by first of all creating its snapshot so I did it this way:

```
const wrapper = (props) =>
    shallow(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Component{...props} />
        </Provider>
    )
        .dive()
        .dive()
        .dive()
        .dive();
```

I had to do `dive()` for so many times because I had to go through all HOC components around it to get correct snapshot with all DOM elements.

I did it this way:

```
 it("renders correctly without error", () => {
        expect(toJson(wrapper())).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
```

and it works correctly. The problem is when I want to pass a prop to that component. It looks like in some way it is overridden by one of the HOC component. I am passing props like this:

```
 const wrapper = shallow(
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Component propName={{ type: 1000 }} />
            </Provider>
        )
            .dive()
            .dive()
            .dive()
            .dive();
```

but in the end I get error from one of the HOC components that `propName` value is null. What can be wrong here? How can I test components like this? Maybe I should use `renderer` method or `mount`?

Comment: that really depends. you can also mock all for returning what the hoc should do without diving. Or you can mount as well as you said, which will render all the tree. but also diving is fine. it really depends on what you wanna test. my personal recommendation is to not test ui interactions/renders through huge snapshots, will result in a huge snapshot hard to mantain and to spot issues on. rather snapshot children eventually or use react testing library for it which gives you more a testing free from implementation details and more "meaningful"

Comment: @quirimmo mock for all returning? can you please show me example? I would like to basically test a complex component if it renders correctly without any errors when I change its props... but I can't because it looks like when I do this `dive()` thing it overrides all props by its HOC components so I can't test it because I get `undefined` prop in the end, so question is how can I test rendering of the component with custom props when it is using multiple HOC components around it?